# Копирование значений нескольких сгенерированных input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ниже указаный код создает несколько `input` с полями для заполнения.

Как после нажатии `button2` скопировать все заполненные значения input?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.sum_value input').click(function() {
     $('#options_value2').html('');
     $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
       $('#options_value2').append($(this).val() + '<input class="text" type="text" value="Мой текст" /><br>');
     });
   });
 });

 $('#button2').on('click', () => {
   let textX = $('#text').html();
   textX = textX;
   
   navigator.clipboard.writeText(textX);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid_css">
    <div class="column_1">
      <ul id="accordion">
        <li>
          <div class="line_All_green">

            <div class="sum_value">

              <div id="1" class="table-td">
                <input type="checkbox" value="11111" id="1_1"><span>A 1</span>
              </div>
              <div id="2" class="table-td">
                <input type="checkbox" value="22222" id="2_2"><span>B 2</span>
              </div>
              <div id="3" class="table-td">
                <input type="checkbox" value="33333" id="3_3"><span>C 3</span>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="column_3">
      <div class="options_sum" id="options_sum">Sum: <span></span></div>Value:
      <div class="options_value2" id="options_value2">
        <p id="options_value2" class="options_value2"></p>
      </div>
      
      <button id="button2" class="button2" > Copy </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто пройтись по всем инпутам и собирать их значения:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sum_value input').click(function() {
    $('#options_value2').html('');
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      $('#options_value2').append($(this).val() + '<input class="text" type="text" value="Мой текст" /><br>');
    });
  });
});

$('#button2').on('click', () => {
  const str = [];
  
  $('#options_value2 .text').each((i, el) => str.push($('input:checkbox:checked').eq(i).parent().find('span').html() + ' ' + el.value));

  navigator.clipboard.writeText(str.join('; '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid_css">
  <div class="column_1">
    <ul id="accordion">
      <li>
        <div class="line_All_green">

          <div class="sum_value">

            <div id="1" class="table-td">
              <input type="checkbox" value="11111" id="1_1"><span>A 1</span>
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="table-td">
              <input type="checkbox" value="22222" id="2_2"><span>B 2</span>
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="table-td">
              <input type="checkbox" value="33333" id="3_3"><span>C 3</span>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="column_3">
    <div class="options_sum" id="options_sum">Sum: <span></span></div>Value:
    <div class="options_value2" id="options_value2">
      <p id="options_value2" class="options_value2"></p>
    </div>

    <button id="button2" class="button2"> Copy </button>
  </div>
</div>

<input placeholder="Paste here"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо. По моему то что хотел.

Comment: @DuKr8 Если мой ответ помог вам, то пожлайуйста примите его, поставив зелёную галочку слева

Comment: у тения ее не видно. подскажите как и обязательно отмечу.

Comment: @DuKr8 Слева от ответа есть стрелочки вниз и вверх, вот под стрелкой вниз, должна быть форма галочки

Comment: поставил.по моему сделал все правильно. и еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @DuKr8 Так я и беру `value`, не очень понял вас. Вообще можете положить абсолютно любой текст

Comment: извините, не value а значение "span"

Comment: чтоб получалось так:
A 1 Мой текст1
B 2 Мой текст2
....

Comment: @DuKr8 Готово, пробуйте

Comment: Спасибо. все работает.